# An LCM related problem

Tags: number-theory

If $A=\{27,42,30,94\}$ is a set, then all possible subsets from the set will be $\{27\}$, $\{42\}$, $\{30\}$, $\{94\}$, $\{27,42\}$, $\{27,30\}$, $\{27,94\}$, $\{42,30\}$, $\{42,94\}$, $\{30,94\}$, $\{27,42,30\}$, $\{27,30,94\}$, $\{27,42,94\}$, $\{42,30,94\}$, $\{27,42,30,94\}$.
The LCM (least common multiple) for all the subsets will be $27,42,30,94,378,270,2538,210,1974,\ldots,17766,9870,88830$.

I found out those lcm i.e lcm of each subset using ladder method. Now I want to know is there any faster and efficient method to find out lcm of every subset above. If so, then what is the method. Please state it with great details.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty set $S$.
Then for each element $a$ of $A$ in turn do the following: If $a\notin S$, let $T=\{a\}$, iterate over the elements $x$ of $S$ and insert $\operatorname{lcm}(x,a)$ into $T$; finally replace $S$ with $S\cup T$. When you're done, $S$ will contain the set of lcms of nonempty subsets of $A$.

Note that in the worst case $|S|=2^{|A|}$, so you cannot expect any faster-than-exponential algorithm anyway. Also note that youdo not need prime factorization as the lcm can be computed from the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

Since lcm is associative, you can find all those lcm by computing *one* lcm per subset: just draw the tree of subsets under addition of one element each time,  start from the bottom and go up.