# Finding out LCM(least common multiple)

Tags: number-theory

The non-empty subsets of
$$
    A=\{27, 42, 30, 94\}
$$
  are 
$$
      \{27\}, \{42\}, \{30\}, 
      \{94\}, \{27,42\}, 
      \{27,30\}, \{27,94\}, …, 
      \{27,42,94\}, \{42,30,94\}, 
      \{27,42,30,94\}.
$$
The LCMs (least common multiples) of all these subsets are `$27, 42, 30, 94, 378, 270, 2538,…,17766, 9870, 88830$.

Now I want to know is there is any faster and efficient method to find out the LCMs of all subsets. If so, then what is the method? Please state it in great detail.

Comment: So you want to avoid computing the subsets, don't you?

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975373/an-lcm-related-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new, just an approach that can be efficiently implemented in a computer programm:

Firstly write down as usual the prime factors of every number: $$27=(3\cdot3\cdot3), \qquad 42=(2\cdot3\cdot7), \qquad 30=(2\cdot3\cdot5), \quad \text{and} \quad 94=(2\cdot47)$$ Now consider the three $3$'s in $27$ as different prime factors, i.e. $3_1, 3_2, 3_3$ and rewrite the above factorizations as $$27=(3_1\cdot3_2\cdot3_3), \qquad 42=(2\cdot3_1\cdot7), \qquad 30=(2\cdot3_1\cdot5), \quad \text{and} \quad 94=(2\cdot47)$$ The LCM of the above for numbers is the product of all the different "elements" that appear in the above factorizations, i.e. $$LCM(27,42,30,94)=3_1\cdot3_2\cdot3_3\cdot2\cdot7\cdot5\cdot47=88830$$
In order to find the LCM of any subset it is useful to write the above product with an indication of which number contributes each factor:
$$LCM(27,42,30,94)=(3_1)_{(27, 42, 30)}\cdot(3_2\cdot3_3)_{(27)}\cdot(2)_{(42,30,94)}\cdot(7)_{(42)}\cdot(5)_{(30)}\cdot(47)_{(94)}=88830$$
Now if you want to exclude for example $27$ and find the LCM of the rest, simply delete $27$ from all the above indices. If a number has empty index - after this deletion - then it should be excluded. Thus, $3_2, 3_3$ will be excluded but not $3_1$. Specifically $$\begin{align*} LCM(42,30,94)&=(3_1)_{(42, 30)}\cdot(3_2\cdot3_3)_{(\emptyset)}\cdot(2)_{(42,30,94)}\cdot(7)_{(42)}\cdot(5)_{(30)}\cdot(47)_{(94)}=\\&=(3_1)_{(42, 30)}\cdot(2)_{(42,30,94)}\cdot(7)_{(42)}\cdot(5)_{(30)}\cdot(47)_{(94)}=\\&=9870\end{align*}$$ This approach can be efficiently implemented in a programm.

Comment: is this method more efficient than (finding all subsets and find out lcm for all the subsets)

Comment: Assuming you have all the subsets, then, yes, this method can be more efficiently implemented that computing the LCM anew for every subset. Now, if you also want to determine all the subsets as well, you need to add another loop, but I cannot tell you how. I think that there will be efficient algorithms to determine all subsets of a given set. As I said, it is nothing new, it just seems to me faster, that's all.